# Error while installing Rails with gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

i'm trying to install Ruby on Rails.
My steps are:

1. sudo apt-get install curl
2. \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
3. sudo apt-get install nodejs
4. gem etc. update
5. gem install rails

At step 5 i get the following error:

> /home/winfo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb creating Makefile
>
> make "DESTDIR=" compiling atomic_reference.c linking shared-object
>   atomic_reference.so
>
> make "DESTDIR=" install ./install -m 0755 atomic_reference.so
>   ./.gem.20131018-11017-3d6vpu make: ./install: Kommando nicht gefunden (Command not found)
>   make: *** [install-so] Fehler 127 (Error 127)

Can anybody help me? I'm new to Ubuntu etc ;)
Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you type `sudo apt-get install make`?

Comment: make is allready installed ;)

Comment: try: 
rvm requirements

Comment: Checking requirements for ubuntu.
Requirements installation successful.
I'm getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

1. sudo apt-get update
2. sudo apt-get install git-core curl zlib1g-dev build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev python-software-properties libffi-dev
3. sudo apt-get install libgdbm-dev libncurses5-dev automake libtool bison libffi-dev nodejs htop nmap
4. gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
5. \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
6. source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
7. rvm install 2.3.1
8. rvm use 2.3.1 --default
9. ruby -v
10. gem install rails